# Open links in Disqus threads in a new tab

Tags: hyperlink, disqus, new-window

Currently I'm using Disqus on my site. It's great, but the only downfall is that when users posts links in their comments and it's clicked on then it sends traffic away from my site.

I want the links to open in a new window/tab. I've emailed Disqus support, and they replied with - "While we don’t currently offer this functionality, we’ve forwarded this as a suggestion to our team for consideration."

From doing a lot of research I am starting to think it's not possible, but if anyone has any suggestions/solutions I would be most grateful.

Comment: Considering this isn't anything you can control, it's probably not a great question to post here. That said, we're making a change on our end that will open links in new tabs/windows, which should address your question.

Comment: Thanks alot Ryan, it was a last resort question, and my hours of googling really gave me no choice.

Comment: Glad you got your answer then :-)

Comment: @Ryan-v are the changes made? I don't see the option in the admin panel, although I did find some other cool stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

From http://giuseppecaruso.tumblr.com/post/9135404514/how-to-make-links-in-disqus-comments-open-in-a-new-windo

Solution? Use jQuery to set target value to _blank.

```
$('.dsq-comment-text a').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: This isn't a viable solution because Disqus loads in an iframe, therefore we cannot access/modify it's contents. (Besides, this wouldn't work with modern versions of jQuery, since the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in 1.9.)